# Unable to continue the test once the nightwatch isVisible condition has met

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightwatch.js

I am using nightwatch `isVisible` command to check for the element visible. The scenario here is , If the element is visible, i want to click that element and continue the test. if the element is not visible, i don't want to click the element and I still want to continue the test.
Therefore , I cannot wrap the code in else block.

The problem here is , once the condition has met , The test doesn't continue. I believe it couldn't come out from that condition. Please find my code below and provide your suggestions.

```
        `       
        const result = await  this.myAccountTest.isVisible('@btnremove');
        console.log('isVisible result', result);
        if(await result.value==true)
        {
            await this.myAccountTest.remove();
            await this.myAccountTest.clickConfirm();

        }
        // rest of the code to continue
        await this.myaccountTest.create();
        //more code`
```

Comment: what is that it is printing in console log for result.value?

Comment: It is printing boolean value  true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using await at wrong places. Maybe you can simply code as below.

```
const result = await this.myAccountTest.isVisible('@btnremove');
console.log('isVisible result', result);
if (result.value) {
  this.myAccountTest.remove();
  this.myAccountTest.clickConfirm();
}
// rest of the code to continue
await this.myaccountTest.create();
```

Comment: Can you please show how to set the suppressNotFoundErrors when we use isVisible command.  I tried like this, it didn't work for me. ```this.myAccountTest.isVisible({selector:'@btnDelete',suppressNotFoundErrors :false});```

Comment: This looks fine. But is that element really not available on the page?

Comment: yes, That element is not available for specific scenario. That's why i have that `if` condition. When the element is not available,  I do not want the error to show up. but even after specifying that `suppressNotFoundErrors `, it still shows error in console. However as you mentioned i was using the `await` in wrong place. so now test works.

Comment: Good luck. Enjoy!